# Inverse of a matrix with small elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $A$ be a square uniform matrix with elements in $[0,k]$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$, $q$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer less than $q$. If $k=q-1$, then we know the exact probability of $A$ being invertible over $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Is there any method to find the exact probability of $A$ being invertible over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ when $k<<q$?